How to most efficiently delete a tuple from a list of tuples based on the first element of the tuple in Python?
I have a data structure as follows,
data = {
    '0_0': [('0_0', 0), ('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 2)],
    '0_1': [('0_0', 1), ('0_1', 0), ('0_2', 1)],
    '0_2': [('0_0', 2), ('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 0)],
}

Each key of the dictionary is unique. The values corresponding to the key value in the dictionary structure are list of tuples, and each tuple contains the coordinate name and the distance to that coordinate.
How to delete tuple from lists by given key? For example I wrote a function as follows,
def remove_all_acs(
    dictionary,
    delete_ac
):
    for key in dictionary:
        acs = dictionary[key]
        for ac in acs:
            if ac[0] == delete_ac:
                acs.remove(ac)
                break

    return dictionary

It's my expected output and returns a result as follows,
print(remove_all_acs(data, '0_0'))
{
    '0_0': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 2)],
    '0_1': [('0_1', 0), ('0_2', 1)],
    '0_2': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 0)]
}

It works but is not effective on large lists. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.
In addition you can create large dataset using this code,
import math

def generate(width, height):
    coordinates = [(x, y) for x in range(width) for y in range(height)]
    dataset = {}
    
    for x1, y1 in coordinates:
        key = f"{x1}_{y1}"
        distances = []
        for x2, y2 in coordinates:
            if (x1, y1) != (x2, y2):
                distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
                distances.append((f"{x2}_{y2}", distance))
        dataset[key] = distances
    
    return dataset


If you're going to be doing a lot of deletes on large lists, perhaps a list is the wrong data structure to use.

Do you have any data structure suggestion for this case?

A dictionary would work well as deletions would occur in O(1).

If each target key could appear at any position in the list, and could appear more than once, then instead of using list.remove(ac) repeatedly, use a list comprehension or filter(func, sequence) to generate a new list while filtering put the tuples you don't want.  Each call to list.remove() requires all of the elements in the list after the element to get moved around.

@nigh_anxiety If you know there will only be one match, testing every element with filter is less efficient than breaking out of the loop when you find a match. Moving around is faster than testing and building a new list.

@Barmar Yes, if each target is guaranteed to appear only once per list, then remove would be more efficient.  If that's not guaranteed, (and the, break were removed) then using remove would fail to remove all elements if the target ever appears at consecutive indexes.

Unfortunately I can't change the data structure because it is used many times in a large project and changing the return type could break a lot of things. I tried filtering but the remove option is still faster.

@E.Zeytinci Is the target tuple to be deleted guaranteed to only appear in each list one time, or could it appear in a given list multiple times? And if it appears multiple times, would all matching tuples be removed or only the first one found?

How often are you planning on removing elements, and how many elements gets removed before the index being read again? Depending on how the structure is used, you might be able to duck type it with your implementation behind the scenes - either skipping deleted elements when iteration happens or using a dict as a backend as suggested.

Do the tuples always have two elements? How large are your actual lists and dict? Is there always a matching tuple in each list?

Is the data type always: dict[str,list[tuple[str,int]]]? If so, I would give Cython a try. There is not much you can do here with pure Python.

I don't know what you want to do with the data afterward, but another thing you can try to convert the data somehow to fit numpy (struct array)/pandas. This is going to be much faster if you don't want to add new data. Instead of deleting the data, set it to np.nan/pd.NA to avoid new memory allocation.

The question is unclear on how many matches there can be for each key. Your attempted solution (which you say "works") assumes only one match per key, while your random data generator produces test data that can have multiple matches per key.

Is this specifically a performance optimization question? Or did you find a case where your code goes wrong? In the latter case, this is way too broad - you would be expected to do the standard debugging, [mre] creating etc. work first.

You're right @blhsing, I added description to my question. I also updated data generation method.

@KarlKnechtel "It works but is not effective on large lists." it's my problem actually so I need to performance optimization.

@E.Zeytinci Did you remove the data = generate(200, 10) by accident? That's important information and guided at least my answer.

@nocomment I just updated generate function, because list should contains unique values. But you still can use data = generate(200, 10).

I just realized you completely changed the data, from a very sparse graph to a complete graph. That's no good.

def remove_all_acs_now(dictionary, delete_ac):
    for key in dictionary:
        acs = dictionary[key]
        for ac in acs:
            if ac[0] == delete_ac:
                acs.remove(ac)
                break

    return dictionary

def remove_all_acs(dictionary, delete_ac):
    for i in dictionary.values(): # .items() / .values() are the fastest ways for dicts, always!
        for q in (i):
            if q[0] == delete_ac:
                i.remove(q)
                break
            
data=generate(200, 10)
from copy import deepcopy
remove_all_acs(dictionary=deepcopy(data), delete_ac="0_0")
remove_all_acs_now(dictionary=deepcopy(data), delete_ac="0_0")

%timeit deepcopy(data) # needed, because we are modifying the original value
502 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit remove_all_acs(dictionary=deepcopy(data), delete_ac="0_0")
539 ms ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
539 - 502 = 37 ms

%timeit remove_all_acs_now(dictionary=deepcopy(data), delete_ac="0_0")
559 ms ± 44.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
559 - 502 = 57 ms

Further improvements:
The function doesn't need to return anything, since you are modifying the original dict anyway. You wouldn't even need to pass the dict to the function if it is available in the function's scope (probably a tiny bit faster).
However, like I stated in my comments: try to use Cython or Numpy (or both) for real (10x or faster) improvements.
Edit - Test with cython - 6 times faster
Cython is at least 6 times faster. The less there is to delete, the faster it is. The speed of Cython's loops is insane. If there is no matching value (which means nothing to delete), it is about 50 times faster.
from cythondicttest import deletefomdict
import random
from copy import deepcopy


def generate(size, max_connections):
    data = {}
    keys = [f"{i}_{j}" for i in range(size) for j in range(size)]

    for key in keys:
        connections = random.randint(1, min(max_connections, 10))
        data[key] = [
            (random.choice(keys), random.randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(connections)
        ]

    return data


def remove_all_acs_now(dictionary, delete_ac):
    for key in dictionary:
        acs = dictionary[key]
        for ac in acs:
            if ac[0] == delete_ac:
                acs.remove(ac)
                break

    return dictionary


data = generate(500, 100)

# %timeit deepcopy(data)
# 3.16 s ± 27.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# %timeit deletefomdict(dictionary=deepcopy(data), delete_ac="0_0")
# 3.2 s ± 26.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# CYTHON:
# 3200 ms - 3160 ms = 40 ms

# %timeit remove_all_acs_now(dictionary=deepcopy(data), delete_ac="0_0")
# 3.41 s ± 122 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# 3410 ms - 3160 ms = 250 ms

And it is not much work to do:
Create a PYX file cythondicttest.pyx, compile it with Cython, and you are ready to go!
# important: use optimized compiler directives
# https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives
cimport cython
import cython

cpdef int deletefomdict(dict[str,list[tuple[str,int]]] dictionary, str delete_ac):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t loop
    for i in dictionary.values():
            loop=len(i)
            for qq in range(loop):
                if i[qq][0] == delete_ac:
                    del i[qq]
                    break
    return 0

If you have never used Cython before, you might use these directives (my default settings) as an orientation, but you might get even better results tweaking the settings here and there.
optionsdict = {
    "Options.docstrings": False,
    "Options.embed_pos_in_docstring": False,
    "Options.generate_cleanup_code": False,
    "Options.clear_to_none": True,
    "Options.annotate": True,
    "Options.fast_fail": False,
    "Options.warning_errors": False,
    "Options.error_on_unknown_names": True,
    "Options.error_on_uninitialized": True,
    "Options.convert_range": True,
    "Options.cache_builtins": True,
    "Options.gcc_branch_hints": True,
    "Options.lookup_module_cpdef": False,
    "Options.embed": False,
    "Options.cimport_from_pyx": False,
    "Options.buffer_max_dims": 8,
    "Options.closure_freelist_size": 8,
}
configdict = {
    "define_macros": [
        ("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", 1),
        ("NPY_1_7_API_VERSION", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_DICT_VERSIONS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_FAST_GIL", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_PYLIST_INTERNALS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_UNICODE_INTERNALS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_ASSUME_SAFE_MACROS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_TYPE_SLOTS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_PYTYPE_LOOKUP", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_ASYNC_SLOTS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_PYLONG_INTERNALS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_UNICODE_WRITER", 1),
        ("CYTHON_UNPACK_METHODS", 1),
        ("CYTHON_USE_EXC_INFO_STACK", 1),
        ("CYTHON_ATOMICS", 1),
    ],
    "undef_macros": [],
    "library_dirs": [],
    "libraries": [],
    "runtime_library_dirs": [],
    "extra_objects": [],
    "extra_compile_args": ["/O2", "/Oy"],
    "extra_link_args": [],
    "export_symbols": [],
    "swig_opts": [],
    "depends": [],
    "language": "c",
    "optional": None,
}

compiler_directives = {
    "binding": True,
    "boundscheck": False,
    "wraparound": False,
    "initializedcheck": False,
    "nonecheck": False,
    "overflowcheck": False,
    "overflowcheck.fold": True,
    "embedsignature": False,
    "embedsignature.format": "c",  # (c / python / clinic)
    "cdivision": True,
    "cdivision_warnings": False,
    "cpow": True,
    "always_allow_keywords": False,
    "c_api_binop_methods": False,
    "profile": False,
    "linetrace": False,
    "infer_types": True,
    "language_level": 3,  # (2/3/3str)
    "c_string_type": "bytes",  # (bytes / str / unicode)
    "c_string_encoding": "default",  # (ascii, default, utf-8, etc.)
    "type_version_tag": False,
    "unraisable_tracebacks": True,
    "iterable_coroutine": True,
    "annotation_typing": True,
    "emit_code_comments": True,
    "cpp_locals": False,
    "legacy_implicit_noexcept": False,
    "optimize.use_switch": True,
    "optimize.unpack_method_calls": True,
    "warn.undeclared": False,  # (default False)
    "warn.unreachable": True,  # (default True)
    "warn.maybe_uninitialized": False,  # (default False)
    "warn.unused": False,  # (default False)
    "warn.unused_arg": False,  # (default False)
    "warn.unused_result": False,  # (default False)
    "warn.multiple_declarators": True,  # (default True)
    "show_performance_hints": True,  # (default True)
}   


Why change their good names to bad ones?

deepcopy is slow. You'd get better timings with dictionary={k: v[:] for k, v in data.items()}.

Just have in mind that, no matter how fast cython loops are, the performance slows down proportionally to the number of iterations (the number of connections in this case). I only advise OP to go this route if about 10 connections is what they will actually see in production.

@Rodrigo Rodrigues I think there is no other way to speed it up significantly without changing the data structure

I know that in a comment you mentioned you cannot change the data structure, but I will post this answer anyway on the following premises:

Someone else might come to this question in a position that they CAN decide and select a better data structure for a scenario like this;
Maybe yourself, after seeing the improvement in results with just a slight change in the data structure, could re-evaluate this constraint.

If the value of the outer dictionary is a inner list of tuples L, the best performance you can get is proportional to traversing L at least once (to find a match), and possibly once again to re-index your list after removing an element. Your current solution is almost as good as it can get, and it is probably not worth to implement a more complex algorithm (like adding cache) for a few % improvement.
Something easy you could theoretically do is to iterate over range(len(acs)) and change acs.remove(ac) for del acs[i] so you don't need to iterate it again to find the index where ac is. But, even this may not be actually faster, because list.remove is very optimized.
Now, what I actually recommend is to change your dictionary values from list[tuple[str, int]] to dict[str, int]. Finding an item in a dict by key is a constant time action, same as removing it, much better than doing so in a list. The difference becomes much more evident if you had a lot of inner connections, instead of a max of 10.
def generate(size, max_connections):
    data = {}
    keys = [f'{i}_{j}' for i in range(size) for j in range(size)]
    
    for key in keys:
        # fixing a small bug, so `max_connections` is respected
        connections = random.randint(1, max_connections)
        # dict constructor, instead of list
        data[key] = {
            random.choice(keys): random.randint(1, 10)
            for _ in range(connections)
        }
    
    return data

def remove_all_acs(dictionary, delete_ac):
    # you should probably change this to `for acs in dictionary.values()` anyway
    for key in dictionary:
        acs = dictionary[key]
        # `in` and `del` are FAST in dict
        if delete_ac in acs:
            del acs[delete_ac]
    return dictionary

That would be the minimal intervention needed, and with just that, even with just 10 connections on each node, you should get 3x faster results.
See some benchmark below:
def test(data, n):
    times = []
    for _ in range(n):
        ac = f"{random.randint(0, len(data) - 1)}_{random.randint(0, len(data) - 1)}"
        start = time.time()
        remove_all_acs(data, ac)
        end = time.time()
        times.append(end - start)
    print(n, "runs, total time:", sum(times))

test(generate(200, 10), 1000)   # 10 connections
# Your original solution: 1000 runs, total time: 16.1 s
# Changing list to dict:  1000 runs, total time:  5.1 s

test(generate(200, 100), 1000)  # 100 connections
# Your original solution: 1000 runs, total time: 71.7 s
# Changing list to dict:  1000 runs, total time:  9.4 s

test(generate(200, 1000), 1000) # 1000 connections
# Your original solution: 1000 runs, total time: (I gave up on waiting)
# Changing list to dict:  1000 runs, total time: 14.1 s


Looks like you are trying to remove a node from a graph, and all associated connections.
Unfortunately, without changing the datastructure, I don't see a faster algorithm.
The deletion could be sped up by manually maintaining a separate cache, e.g. a set of items that don't have a connection to the deleted item, and skip them when deleting. Of course this cache will have to be updated too when inserting a new connection.
Just in case, this other SO question refers two good libraries to store graphs:

NetworkX
igraph


Searching and removing a tuple with ANY second value seems ~twice as fast in some testing I did (with their original data generator before they completely changed it from a very sparse to a complete graph).
from unittest.mock import ANY

def remove_all_acs(
    dictionary,
    delete_ac
):
    delete = delete_ac, ANY
    for acs in dictionary.values():
        if delete in acs:
            acs.remove(delete)
    return dictionary


Probably due to: dictionary.values() which is faster than: acs = dictionary[key]

@Hans Maybe. Your 44.8 ms stdev looks too large to draw a conclusion.

@Hans Looks like the majority of my speed increase comes from my tuple thing. Deleting just one key, I get like 22 ms for their original, 19 for yours, and 13 for mine.

It seems wasteful to perform the same search twice, once with in and another with list.remove. I would enclose list.remove in a try block with a handler that supresses exceptions.

@blhsing I tried that and as expected, it was much slower. Look at their numbers. delete in acs has very low probability, so I rarely do a double search and you'd have lots of exceptions. And catching exceptions is expensive.

Right, it totally depends on the percentage of lists that contain a match.

Perhaps use list.index to perform the search once and then del the index if found.

@blhsing Surely that would be even slower?

How would that be slower? It would perform the search once as opposed to two with list.remove.

Oops I was under the impression that list.index returns -1 when not found when it actually raises an exception. My bad.

@blhsing try+index+del would be even slower than try+remove, no?

Yeah, sad that there's no parallel of str.find for list.

@RodrigoRodrigues' answer provides a good framework for testing solutions, which I've copied (with some modifications) below.
However, be careful — the shape of your workload might really affect the answer! The testing framework below reuses the same data for 100 mutations in a row, which means that the dict is getting smaller and smaller and ultimately it might end up caring a lot about the performance on a small dict and/or on a dict which does not contain the key. Is that very important to you? or very unimportant?
The one change it seems like you should make is that instead of
for key in dictionary:
    acs = dictionary[key]
    for ac in acs:

you should just write:
for acs in dictionary.values():
    for ac in acs:

That saves one key lookup, everything else remaining the same; so I'd think that it must be faster. But if there's any difference, it's down in the noise; everything else we're doing is vastly more expensive than a hash lookup. So really the justification for this change is just that it looks cleaner, being one line of code shorter.
import random
import time

def generate(size, max_connections):
    data = {}
    keys = ['%d_%d' % (random.randint(1, size), i) for i in range(size)]
    for key in keys:
        connections = random.randint(1, max_connections)
        data[key] = [
            (random.choice(keys), 42)
            for _ in range(connections)
        ]
    return keys, data

def remove_all_acs1(dictionary, delete_ac):
    for key in dictionary:
        acs = dictionary[key]
        for ac in acs:
            if ac[0] == delete_ac:
                acs.remove(ac)
                break

def remove_all_acs2(dictionary, delete_ac):
    for acs in dictionary.values():
        for ac in acs:
            if ac[0] == delete_ac:
                acs.remove(ac)
                break

def remove_all_acs3(dictionary, delete_ac):
    for acs in dictionary.values():
        for i, ac in enumerate(acs):
            if ac[0] == delete_ac:
                acs.pop(i)
                break

def remove_all_acs4(dictionary, delete_ac):
    for key, acs in dictionary.items():
        dictionary[key] = [(k, v) for (k, v) in acs if k != delete_ac]

def remove_all_acs5(dictionary, delete_ac):
    class Trick:
        def __eq__(self, ac):
            return ac[0] == delete_ac
    t = Trick()
    for acs in dictionary.values():
        try:
            acs.remove(t)
        except:
            pass

def test(raa, k, c, n):
    keys, data = generate(k, c)
    keys_to_delete = [random.choice(keys) for _ in range(n)]
    started = time.time()
    for delete_ac in keys_to_delete:
        raa(data, delete_ac)
    elapsed = (time.time() - started)
    print("%s, %d keys, %d connections: %d runs took %.3f seconds" % (raa.__name__, k, c, n, elapsed))

test(remove_all_acs1, 2000, 10, 100)
test(remove_all_acs2, 2000, 10, 100)
test(remove_all_acs3, 2000, 10, 100)
test(remove_all_acs4, 2000, 10, 100)
test(remove_all_acs5, 2000, 10, 100)

test(remove_all_acs1, 20000, 100, 100)
test(remove_all_acs2, 20000, 100, 100)
test(remove_all_acs3, 20000, 100, 100)
test(remove_all_acs4, 20000, 100, 100)
test(remove_all_acs5, 20000, 100, 100)

On my machine, I get these timings:
remove_all_acs1, 2000 keys, 10 connections: 100 runs took 0.028 seconds
remove_all_acs2, 2000 keys, 10 connections: 100 runs took 0.024 seconds
remove_all_acs3, 2000 keys, 10 connections: 100 runs took 0.040 seconds
remove_all_acs4, 2000 keys, 10 connections: 100 runs took 0.054 seconds
remove_all_acs5, 2000 keys, 10 connections: 100 runs took 0.089 seconds

remove_all_acs1, 20000 keys, 100 connections: 100 runs took 2.021 seconds
remove_all_acs2, 20000 keys, 100 connections: 100 runs took 1.972 seconds
remove_all_acs3, 20000 keys, 100 connections: 100 runs took 2.603 seconds
remove_all_acs4, 20000 keys, 100 connections: 100 runs took 4.155 seconds
remove_all_acs5, 20000 keys, 100 connections: 100 runs took 6.307 seconds


Could you include mine as well?

And I'm curious about a LBYL version of solution 5.

Dictionary Comprehension: For large datasets, this approach should be quite efficient. It has a time complexity proportional to the size of the dataset
import pandas as pd

data = {
    '0_0': [('0_0', 0), ('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 2)],
    '0_1': [('0_0', 1), ('0_1', 0), ('0_2', 1)],
    '0_2': [('0_0', 2), ('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 0)],
}


delete_ac = '0_0'

data_filtered = {
    k : [(ac,dist) for ac,dist in v if ac != delete_ac ]

for k,v in data.items()    
}
print(data_filtered)
"""
{'0_0': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 2)], 
'0_1': [('0_1', 0), ('0_2', 1)], 
'0_2': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 0)]}
"""

# Create a DataFrame from the modified dictionary
df_filtered = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_filtered, orient='index', columns=['Coordinate', 'Distance'])

print(df_filtered)
"""
   Coordinate  Distance
0_0   (0_1, 1)  (0_2, 2)
0_1   (0_1, 0)  (0_2, 1)
0_2   (0_1, 1)  (0_2, 0)

"""

OR:
delete_ac = '0_0'
aa = { k :[(k1,v1) for k1,v1 in v if not k1.startswith(delete_ac)] for k,v in data.items()}
print(aa)
"""
{'0_0': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 2)], '0_1': [('0_1', 0), ('0_2', 1)], '0_2': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 0)]}
"""


The following short and easy-to-understand function returns a dictionary without the undesired tuples. It also works on large lists.
def remove_all_acs(dictionary, delete_ac):
    temp={}
    for x in dictionary:
        temp[x]=[t for t in dictionary[x] if t[0] != delete_ac]
    return temp 

Based on your example, we have:
print(remove_all_acs(data, '0_0'))
{'0_0': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 2)], 
 '0_1': [('0_1', 0), ('0_2', 1)], 
 '0_2': [('0_1', 1), ('0_2', 0)]}

